# matplob animation plot scatter

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'm trying to animate the Monte Carlo method to calculate PI but I have a problem, after drawing a plot it disappears, literally it is remplace by new plot in other position.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


fig = plt.figure()
plt.xlim(0, 1)
plt.ylim(0, 1)
graph, = plt.plot([], [], 'o')

tries = 1000
inside = 0
dot = np.random.rand(tries, 2)

def animate(i):
    graph.set_data(dot[i][0], dot[i][1])


for i in range(0, tries):
    if np.sqrt(dot[i][0]**2 + dot[i][1]**2) < 1:
        inside += 1
        animate(i)
    else:
        animate(i)

print (float(inside) / tries) * 4

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=20, interval=200)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your plots are being replaced by a new single point on each iteration is due to the line in the `animate` function. You have created a `Line2D` object, and you are setting its value to a single point each time. One way to rectify this is to make a simple change to this line, and the function becomes:

```
def animate(i):
    graph.set_data((dot[:i,0],), (dot[:i,1],))
```

Because of the structure of the `dot` variable, the colons before the index cause all elements rows 0 to i-1 in the respective columns to be sent to the `Line2D` object. So on each iteration you are replacing the previous set of points with a new set containing one more point.

If this is not what you want let me know via comments.